# Trouble with iterating through an array from SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm getting a compile time error of "Cannot subscript a type of Element aka (String, JSON) with an index of type String"

```
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    let strHighlights = []

                    for item in json {
                        if let uname = item["uname"].string { //it doesn't like this line
                            strHighlights.append(uname)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the SwiftyJSON object with a `(String, JSON)` tuple.

```
for (key, item) in json {
    if let uname = item["uname"].string {
        strHighlights.append(uname)
    }
}
```

And since we don't use the key here we can ignore it:

```
for (_, item) in json {
    if let uname = item["uname"].string {
        strHighlights.append(uname)
    }
}
```